# Button Pressed when swipe from one button to another in Android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-studio, gesture-recognition

[image: Here is an example from ios app]

I am creating a word guessing app, in which words can be created by swiping the buttons, i don't know how to implement the Touch event on buttons so that button can be pressed without lifting the thumb.  Like the WordBrain App in the IOS
(https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/wordbrain/id708600202?mt=8). Like Swipe Keyboard in android, we write the words without lifting our thumb.

I need to know the listeners to recognize the gesture when touch enter the another button dimensions and get the text of that button. Thanks

Comment: I have seen many examples but couldn't find the perfect one for this work. Kindly help me. Thanks

Comment: Your question is unclear. I don't know this WordBrain app nor I want to install it to answer your question (and I don't have an iOS device anyway). What exactly you want to do? You want to be notified when a button is pressed but not released? What has swipe to do with this?

Comment: I want to move from one button to another like swipe keyboard in Android..

Comment: Still unclear. What does "move one button to another" mean? Don't be shy, detail.

Comment: I mean to say when i touch the screen and move my thumbs on screen, when i reach the button an event occurs which get the text of that button and so on when move to anther button it also get the text of that button... Got it?

Comment: "when i touch the screen and move my thumbs on screen" Why would you that? To drag something? Do you mean drag and drop a button over another?

Comment: I edit my question i think now it will be clear.

Comment: I see your picture, that's much clearer now. What you want is called "drag and drop".

Comment: Did you check other questions and answers about this? For example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20610288/android-how-to-simply-drag-and-drop-a-button. If it didn't help, please state why.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78078/discussion-between-shahrooz-saleem-and-m0skit0).

Comment: It didn't helped me out. i want a general solution for all my buttons.